# Ajax return value from php to textbox without posting value to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, textbox, return-value

I want to get the value from php and set to the textbox.

Here is my ajax code:

```
 function docnum(){

$.ajax({
        url: 'docnum.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'json_encode': $('#tanggal').val()
              },
        success: function(data){
            $('#number2').val(data);
                  }
    });
}
```

and here is my html code

```
<input type="text" id="number2" name="number2" placeholder="number2" onClick="docnum()" />
```

and here is my php code docnum.php

```
      <?php
   $counternew="dummyvariable";
    print  json_encode($counternew);

    ?>
```

Why the $counternew can not set to the number2 texbox?
Please help me

Comment: Please format your code, please post only the relevent bits. please avoid the use of mysql_* query functions.

Comment: I have edited my post. thank you for your suggestion

Comment: what is the current result? Is "number2" getting updated with anything?

Comment: Nothing happen. Number2 is only processed by that function. Is there any mistakes on my coding?

Comment: Your PHP does not read the input from the AJAX call.